# EF Core : how to re-scaffold without losing custom changes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-5, scaffolding

There is a WPF application that is currently transitioning from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core 5 (database provider is Oracle, the application uses .NET 5 so EF Core 6 isn't possible currently).

There is one big issue to solve: two scaffolded data types weren't correct (from bool to byte and from bool to int). I changed those types manually. If I now re-scaffold, those changes will be removed for sure.

So my question: is there any possibility to re-scaffold (using the `-force` parameter) without losing the manually changed types OR is there any possibility to override the types which will be generated by scaffolding?

In Entity Framework 6, we used custom data type on EDMX creation to solve this issue:

[image: Custom data types]

What I tried and missed: creating a partial class with the same class name (but different file name) which only contained my changes.

The reason why I'm not using migrations is that I use different database stages.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use partial  classes and methods

Answer (score 2):

> What I tried and missed: creating a partial class with the same class name (but different file name) which only contained my changes.

This will work with the caveat that when the db is re-scaffed the new entities will have the same props appear again (but wrongly typed) and if they're also defined in your partial class you'll get a compile error due to two members having the same name

I'd recommend you install EFCore Power Tools extension and use it to scaff (Reverse Engineer) because there's a section of the "wizard" where it asks you which things you want to scaff and you can untick those columns in the DB to omit them from the models. If they take part in some relationship or have atypical properties meaning they get special attention in the fluent config then you might have to consider an alternative strategy that I use a lot; scaff to a different folder and then run a diff tool to help you merge changes into the main model, then delete the new scaff set.

I leave myself comments in the context that "is the main one", such as "//do not remove this enum column config during context merge", having set up some fluent blah that I know will not be present in the new scaffing

EFCPT does also have some abilities to customize the generated code but I don't know if it goes as far as entirely rewriting parts (I've never looked). It's open source so you can also look at modifying it to meet your needs

Comment: Thank you, these are some great tips to work around an issue that EF Core probably wasn't designed for. I'd love to be able to work model first but sadly that's not possible.